# Removable singularity at infinity implies the Laurent series has no positive powers

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that f(z) is analytic on the complex plane minus a single point $z_0$. Suppose further that f has a simple pole at $z_0$ and a removable singularity at infinity. Prove that $f(z) = \frac{A}{z − z_0} + B$

Since $z_0$ is a simple pole, we know the Laurent series around $z_0$ is of the form $f(z) = \frac{A}{z − z_0} + B + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n (z - z_0 )^n $
where $a_n = \frac{1}{2 \pi i}\int_C \frac{f(z)}{(z - z_0)^{n+1}} dz$. 
And $ a_n = - Res_{w=0} \frac{1}{w^2}\frac{f(\frac{1}{w})}{(\frac{1}{w} -z_0)^{n+1}}$ by the change of variable $z = \frac{1}{w}$. Since z = ∞ is a removable singularity of f(z), we also know $lim_{x \to \infty} zf(\frac{1}{z}) = 0$. However, I'm not sure if I am missing something or how to finish the argument that $a_n = 0$ for all $n > 0$

Comment: You almost have it.  Render $w=1/(\color{blue}{z-z_0})$.

Comment: Estimate your contour integral for $a_n$ where $C$ is a circle of radius $r$, using the fact that $f$ is bounded near $\infty$, and take $r \to \infty$.